# Generate common webservice java client code based on two wsdl

Tags: java, cxf, webservice-client

I am trying to implement some common code between Exchange 2007 and 2010 using a WSDL file provided by a company I am working with.  Let's say that for the most part the wsdl has only had minor changes between 2007 and 2010.  Now when I generate new code based on the wsdl (I use cxf-apache) I get two separate packages, one for 2007 and 2010.  This means I would need to fill in code to use both 2007 and 2010 differently since they have slightly different changes.

My question is, is there a simpler way to do this?  I don't want to have to write another 5 classes in the future when microsoft decides to release exchange 2013.